# Securities Token contract

Tags: solidity, tokens, security

I want to learn how to create a security token. I am not able to find any sources to teach myself how to. Please, can anyone help me with this situation?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this forum cannot answer legal questions.

Comment: You might want to ask this question in the [Law StackExchange](https://law.stackexchange.com/). To get a satisfying answer, you might also want to provide more details about the problem that you are facing.

Comment: This is not a legal question, this is a question regarding the creation of the ERC1400 contract(security standard token).

Comment: I'm sorry. In that case, it would be helpful to edit your question body to add more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at this video to learn how to create a ERC1400 contract(security standard token):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TegyVjk8ejM